# Search csv for string in column and display only spcific columns

Tags: python, pandas, csv

What I would like to do is search for a string in 1 column of a very large CSV file with 70+ columns.

Once the rows in which that string appears are found I would like to only display data in a specific set of columns.

Here is what I have the keeps giving me errors

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('output.csv')
#columns I would like to display data from
df[df.iloc[0,1,2,11,12,14]] 
#search for specific term in specific column
df.loc[df['COLUMN NAME'].str.contains('SEARCH TERM')]
```

0,1,2,11,12,14 are the index numbers of the columns I would like to display. The other columns have data I am not concerned with.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('output.csv')
df.loc[df['COLUMN NAME'].str.contains('SEARCH TERM')]
```

The above code gives me all the data from all columns when the string is found but it is too much useless data for this simple application.

This feels like a super simple fix but I can't seem to figure it out.

Thank you in advance for any assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **usecol** panda.read_csv constructor parameter to define which columns you need. [Wiki: read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

> usecols : list-like or callable, default None
>
> Return a subset of the columns. If list-like, all elements must either
>   be positional (i.e. integer indices into the document columns) or
>   strings that correspond to column names provided either by the user in
>   names or inferred from the document header row(s). For example, a
>   valid list-like usecols parameter would be [0, 1, 2] or [‘foo’, ‘bar’,
>   ‘baz’]. Element order is ignored, so usecols=[0, 1] is the same as [1,
>   0]. To instantiate a DataFrame from data with element order preserved
>   use pd.read_csv(data, usecols=['foo', 'bar'])[['foo', 'bar']] for
>   columns in ['foo', 'bar'] order or pd.read_csv(data, usecols=['foo',
>   'bar'])[['bar', 'foo']] for ['bar', 'foo'] order.
>
> If callable, the callable function will be evaluated against the
>   column names, returning names where the callable function evaluates to
>   True. An example of a valid callable argument would be lambda x:
>   x.upper() in ['AAA', 'BBB', 'DDD']. Using this parameter results in
>   much faster parsing time and lower memory usage.

So in Your case, it will be:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(
    'output.csv',
    usecols=[0,1,2,11,12,14]
)
df.loc[df['COLUMN NAME'].str.contains('SEARCH TERM')]
```

You can provide either array of column id's or array of names

Hope it helps